# Possible to exclude folders with certain names while using Amazon AWS CLI?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I've just starting working with Amazon's AWS CLI to backup my VPS server's apps. The issue I'm having is trying to exclude certain folders from syncing.

Ideally this will be run as one single bash script on a CRON job and therefore I was seeing if it was possible to exclude the folders based on a pattern rather than by explicitly setting each absolute path?

As a second best solution, I'm trying to exclude certain filenames instead to reduce the amount of cache and session files that end up getting sent to S3 on backups.

```
aws s3 sync /mypath/apps s3://bucketname --delete --exclude "sess*" --exclude "*.ser" --exclude "*.log"
```

It seems like the `.ser` and `.log` files are being ignored but not files with names like `sess_12a8b7886206bf7d0bb`.

Would anybody be able to confirm of folder names can be targeted or perhaps advise on a way to target the `sess_...` files?

Thanks!

Comment: Is "sess_12a8b7886206bf7d0bb" a file or directory?

Comment: to exclude a folder you need to indicate `/` at the end like `aws s3 sync /mypath/apps s3://bucketname --delete --exclude "sess*/" ...`

Comment: Have you tried using the recursive flag `--recursive`?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I;ve just this minute tried something and I "think" it might be working. As an example `--exclude "*/local/cache/*"`

Comment: `--recursive` seems to cause an error

Comment: @drewyupdrew `recursive` works with `cp` not `sync`

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Gotcha, just figured it was worth a try.  Yeah, it works with cp mv and rm, just wasn't sure if it applied to sync too.  Thanks, learn something new everyday.  Btw though, it sounds like it's a file not a directory since OP said, "but not files with names like `sess_12a8b7886206bf7d0bb`"

Comment: Thanks guys, you're right the `sess...` were files not folders but my ideal scenario is dealing with folders anyway. Does it seem like my solution  using the wildcards before and after folder names "should" work? On my quick test it does appear to be having the desired effect yet haven't seen it mentioned in the AWS CLI docs